# How I can connect dialogflow bot to R random forest?

Tags: r, dialogflow-es

Sorry I am new in chatbot.

I am trying to see how connect dialogflow chatbot to a random forest in order to the chatbot give an apropiate answer based on the user input verbatim.
I had a trained randomforest but I am looking for some way to connect this randomfores to dialogflow

Comment: Please consider doing some research on your own and coming back with a specific problem statement, this question may be seen as too general.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow offers three different types of APIs: **query API**, to get what you Dialogflow agent says to users, **agent API** to edit your agents intents, entities and contexts and the **webhook API** to use Dialogflow's NLU to fulfill user's requests:

[image]

**Links to documentation**

v1

- Query API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query
- Agent API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents
- Webhook API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

v2 BETA

- detect intent API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent
- Agent API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents
- Webhook API: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/WebhookRequest